# Telescope deployed on Heroku vs Meteor?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I'm quite new to this...

Why is the documentation saying to deploy on meteor but on the website there's a button to deploy on Heroku? They're completely different right?

When I deployed the telescope app on heroku, I'm missing some tooltips that I've seen on youtube videos, and its not exactly the same. Is it because it was deployed on Heroku?

Comment: Meteor offers its servers basically for testing. Whereas Heroku is proper hosting service. On the Meteor servers you can't have your own domain for example. You can only have a subdomain e.g. mydomain.meteor.com

Comment: Whether you deploy to Heroku or Meteor won't affect the content of your app. Those videos might just be out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to take the position Heroku servers are better. Both are the same to be honest.

Both will switch off your app after a period of inactivity. Both are run on EC2.

One thing with Meteor's servers is you have more resources for your app than on Heroku.

That being said Meteor's Galaxy system is under active deployment so when they push updates up it seems to cut off alot. As it progresses they're aiming for higher quality apps.

I would recommend the Meteor deploy service over Heroku for this reason.

Comment: But what @mwarren said above in the comment is that Meteor is only for testing? If I have my own domain name, Heroku would be best?

Comment: @andrewliu Meteor doesn't offer its servers only for 'testing'. They host their own `meteor.com` website on it! People say this because of the hiccups experienced once in a while since they've been upgrading galaxy

Comment: You can also have your own domain on it, e.g `meteor deploy yourwebsite.com` and if you set your DNS to cname to origin.meteor.com (or A address to an ip address of origin.meteor.com)